# Use of the term "page fault" not relating to virtual memory?

Tags: terminology

In a number of situation, I've found my self using the term "page fault" to describe something other then virtual memory. For example:

- When manually refactoring a block of code into a function, I "page fault" the variable I need into the argument list, that is I start with a void list and add whatever the compiler tells me is missing until things compile.
- When working with a new system I generally take guesses at how it works and only "page fault" knowledge from the docs when my first one or two guesses don't work.

Is this (mis)use of the term to describe error driven advancement common?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard it used either of those ways, although I don't work in an environment where the official meaning is used that much either.